# How to kill from GNOME an application that is stuck and doesn't want to end (here: IntelliJ)?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, gnome

After some tests running, I was willing to look at the failsafe reports they created.

I did a *File/Open* that made the box below appearing, and I've opened the `target` folder to list its sub-folders.

But I could not do more: *IntelliJ* then stuck, surely attempting to prepare in advance something very clever... When I only need it to allow me to reach the `failsafe-reports` folder, and open it, to open five `txt` file inside it...

[image]

The problem is that I cannot close it.

Under *GNOME* I can click as many times I wish on its close cross, or use *Activities* (Windows key) and do that here, it has no effect.
A window doesn't come to ask me "*This application isn't responding, do you want to stop it?*"

I can (and I will) stop it by the mean of a `kill` command issued from the command line.

But is there a way to force kill an application by the mean of GNOME, only?